# Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, loops, for-loop

In other words, can I do something like

```
for() {
    for {
       for {
       }
    }
}
```

Except N times? In other words, when the method creating the loops is called, it is given some parameter N, and the method would then create N of these loops nested one in another?

Of course, the idea is that there should be an "easy" or "the usual" way of doing it. I already have an idea for a very complicated one.

Comment: Can you clarify what parameters would be within each for()?

Comment: I'm just curious, what was your "complicated" way of doing n-level loops?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to look into [recursion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: This still does not answer the question. For-iteration IS a kind of recursion. Perhaps you intend to include an example of *mutual* recursion?

Answer (score 34):

jjnguy is right; recursion lets you dynamically create variable-depth nesting. However, you don't get access to data from the outer layers without a little more work. The "in-line-nested" case:

```
for (int i = lo; i < hi; ++i) {
    for (int j = lo; j < hi; ++j) {
        for (int k = lo; k < hi; ++k) {
            // do something **using i, j, and k**
        }
    }
}
```

keeps the variables `i`, `j`, and `k` in scope for the innermost body to use.

Here's one quick hack to do that:

```
public class NestedFor {

    public static interface IAction {
        public void act(int[] indices);
    }

    private final int lo;
    private final int hi;
    private final IAction action;

    public NestedFor(int lo, int hi, IAction action) {
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void nFor (int depth) {
        n_for (0, new int[0], depth);
    }

    private void n_for (int level, int[] indices, int maxLevel) {
        if (level == maxLevel) {
            action.act(indices);
        } else {
            int newLevel = level + 1;
            int[] newIndices = new int[newLevel];
            System.arraycopy(indices, 0, newIndices, 0, level);
            newIndices[level] = lo;
            while (newIndices[level] < hi) {
                n_for(newLevel, newIndices, maxLevel);
                ++newIndices[level];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `IAction` interface stipulates the role of a controlled action which takes an array of indices as the argument to its `act` method.

In this example, each instance of `NestedFor` is configured by the constructor with the iteration limits and the action to be performed by the innermost level. The parameter of the `nFor` method specifies how deeply to nest.

Here's a sample usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        final int depth = i;
        System.out.println("Depth " + depth);
        IAction testAction = new IAction() {
            public void act(int[] indices) {
                System.out.print("Hello from level " + depth + ":");
                for (int i : indices) { System.out.print(" " + i); }
                System.out.println();
            }
        };
        NestedFor nf = new NestedFor(0, 3, testAction);
        nf.nFor(depth);
    }
}
```

and the (partial) output from its execution:

```
Depth 0
Hello from level 0:
Depth 1
Hello from level 1: 0
Hello from level 1: 1
Hello from level 1: 2
Depth 2
Hello from level 2: 0 0
Hello from level 2: 0 1
Hello from level 2: 0 2
Hello from level 2: 1 0
Hello from level 2: 1 1
Hello from level 2: 1 2
Hello from level 2: 2 0
Hello from level 2: 2 1
Hello from level 2: 2 2
Depth 3
Hello from level 3: 0 0 0
Hello from level 3: 0 0 1
Hello from level 3: 0 0 2
Hello from level 3: 0 1 0
...
Hello from level 3: 2 1 2
Hello from level 3: 2 2 0
Hello from level 3: 2 2 1
Hello from level 3: 2 2 2
```

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, the explicit recursion occurs in the private n_for method on the NestedFor class. (I would write this differently in Java 8, of course :)

Comment: What is this IAction class you are using? I cannot find what I should import to use it...

Comment: It's not a separate class, it's an interface that joel.neely defines at the top. Then whatever you want to do at the end of the for loop, you would have to write a separate class that implements IAction and has something in act(int[] indices).

Answer (score 7):

**2015 Edit:** Along the same vain as the previous incantation, I made the following package to handle this; https://github.com/BeUndead/NFor

The usage would be as follows

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    NFor<Integer> nfor = NFor.of(Integer.class)
            .from(0, 0, 0)
            .by(1, 1, 1)
            .to(2, 2, 3);

    for (Integer[] indices : nfor) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(indices));
    }
}
```

resulting in

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
```

It also supports conditions other than `lessThan`.  The usage there being (with `import static NFor.*;`):

```
NFor<Integer> nfor = NFor.of(Integer.class)
        .from(-1, 3, 2)
        .by(1, -2, -1)
        .to(lessThanOrEqualTo(1), greaterThanOrEqualTo(-1), notEqualTo(0));
```

Resulting in:

```
[-1, 3, 2]
[-1, 3, 1]
[-1, 1, 2]
[-1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, 2]
[-1, -1, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, -1, 2]
[0, -1, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, -1, 2]
[1, -1, 1]
```

Obviously, loops of different lengths and different classes (all boxed, numeric primitives) are supported.  The default (if not specified) is from(0, ...).by(1, ...); but a to(...) must be specified.

The `NForTest` file should demonstrate several different ways to use it.

The basic premise of this being to simply advance the 'indices' each turn rather than use recursion.

Comment: Great answer. I prefer this one over recursion

Comment: This is a great approach, I'd wrap it in a nice class and provide a callback to make it neater...

Answer (score 5):

You might want to explain what you really want to do.

If the outer `for` loops are doing nothing but controlling a count, then your nested `for` loops are simply a more complicated way of iterating by a count that could be handled by a single `for` loop.

For example:

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
  for (y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
    for (z = 0; z < 20; ++z) {
      DoSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (x = 0; x < 10*5*20; ++x) {
  DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Good answer. This captures the essence of nesting loops. See my answer for a generalization of this idea.

Answer (score 5):

I was actually thinking about this the other day.

An example that is probably not perfect but pretty close to what I think is being asked would be printing out a directory tree

```
public void printTree(directory) {
   for(files in directory) {
      print(file);
      if(file is directory) {
          printTree(file);
      }
   }
}
```

this way you end up with a stack of for loops nested inside each other, without the hassle of figuring out exactly how they should go together.

Comment: This is a typical use for recursion, where you are traversing a recursive datastructure.

Answer (score 3):

The essential idea behind nesting loops is **multiplication**.

Expanding on Michael Burr's answer, if the outer `for` loops are doing nothing but controlling a count, then your nested `for` loops over `n` counts are simply a more complicated way of iterating over the product of the counts with a single `for` loop.

Now, let's extend this idea to Lists. If you're iterating over three lists in nested loops, this is simply a more complicated way of iterating over the product of the lists with a single loop. But how do you express the product of three lists?

First, we need a way of expressing the product of types. The product of two types `X` and `Y` can be expressed as a generic type like `P2<X, Y>`. This is just a value that consists of two values, one of type `X`, the other of type `Y`. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class P2<A, B> {
  public abstract A _p1();
  public abstract B _p2();
}
```

For a product of three types, we just have `P3<A, B, C>`, with the obvious third method. A product of three lists, then, is achieved by distributing the List functor over the product type. So the product of `List<X>`, `List<Y>`, and `List<Z>` is simply `List<P3<X, Y, Z>>`. You can then iterate over this list with a single loop.

The [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) library has a `List` type that supports multiplying lists together using first-class functions and product types (P2, P3, etc. which are also included in the library).

For example:

```
for (String x : xs) {
   for (String y : ys) {
     for (String z : zs) {
       doSomething(x, y, z);
     }
   }
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (P3<String, String, String> p : xs.map(P.p3()).apply(ys).apply(zs)) {
   doSomething(p._1(), p._2(), p._3());
}
```

Going further with Functional Java, you can make `doSomething` first-class, as follows. Let's say `doSomething` returns a String:

```
public static final F<P3<String, String, String>, String> doSomething =
  new F<P3<String, String, String>, String>() {
    public String f(final P3<String, String, String> p) {
      return doSomething(p._1(), p._2(), p._3());
    }
  };
```

Then you can eliminate the for-loop altogether, and collect the results of all the applications of `doSomething`:

```
List<String> s = xs.map(P.p3()).apply(ys).apply(zs).map(doSomething);
```

Comment: Isn't this actually employing recursion as well internally?

Comment: I appreciate the connection with multiplication, but it seems to break down if we move away from "bounds" known prior the outer level. If one has e.g. `for (shelf : library) {for (book : shelf) {for (page : book) {...}}}` that has a different "shape" than the one resulting from `xs`, `ys`, and `zs` being established outside the entire construct.

Comment: @joel.neely That is totally true, and you've articulated the difference between applicative functors (used in this answer) and monads.

Answer (score 2):

Problem needs more specification.  Maybe recursion will help you, but keep in mind that recursion is almost always an alternative to iteration, and vice versa.  It may be that a 2-level nested loop can be sufficient for your needs.  Just let us know what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The neatest general approach I could come up with in Java 7 is

```
// i[0] = 0..1  i[1]=0..3, i[2]=0..4
MultiForLoop.loop( new int[]{2,4,5}, new MultiForLoop.Callback() { 
    void act(int[] i) { 
        System.err.printf("%d %d %d\n", i[0], i[1], i[2] );
    }
}
```

Or in Java 8:

```
// i[0] = 0..1  i[1]=0..3, i[2]=0..4
MultiForLoop.loop( new int[]{2,4,5}, 
   i -> { System.err.printf("%d %d %d\n", i[0], i[1], i[2]; } 
);
```

An implementation that supports this is:

```
/**
 * Uses recursion to perform for-like loop.
 *  
 * Usage is 
 *  
 *    MultiForLoop.loop( new int[]{2,4,5}, new MultiForLoop.Callback() { 
 *        void act(int[] indices) { 
 *            System.err.printf("%d %d %d\n", indices[0], indices[1], indices[2] );
 *        }
 *    }
 *  
 * It only does 0 - (n-1) in each direction, no step or start 
 * options, though they could be added relatively trivially.
 */
public class MultiForLoop {

    public static interface Callback {
        void act(int[] indices);
    }

    static void loop(int[] ns, Callback cb) {
        int[] cur = new int[ns.length];
        loop(ns, cb, 0, cur);
    }

    private static void loop(int[] ns, Callback cb, int depth, int[] cur) {
        if(depth==ns.length) {
            cb.act(cur);
            return;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j<ns[depth] ; ++j ) {
            cur[depth]=j;
            loop(ns,cb, depth+1, cur);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are having a general nested-loop structure like:

```
for(i0=0;i0<10;i0++)
    for(i1=0;i1<10;i1++)
        for(i2=0;i2<10;i2++)
            ....
                for(id=0;id<10;id++)
                    printf("%d%d%d...%d\n",i0,i1,i2,...id);
```

where `i0,i1,i2,...,id` are loop variables and `d` is the depth of the nested loop.

Equivalent Recursion Solution:

```
void nestedToRecursion(counters,level){
    if(level == d)
        computeOperation(counters,level);
    else
    {
        for (counters[level]=0;counters[level]<10;counters[level]++)
            nestedToRecursion(counters,level+1);
    }
}
void computeOperation(counters,level){
    for (i=0;i<level;i++)
        printf("%d",counters[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

counters is an array of size `d`, representing the corresponding variables `i0,i1,i2,...id` respectively `int counters[d]`.

```
nestedToRecursion(counters,0);
```

Similarly we can convert other variables like initializing of recursion or ending by using arrays for them, i.e. we could have `initial[d], ending[d]`.

Answer (score 2):

A Java 8 solution based on streams:

```
public static Stream<int[]> nest(Supplier<IntStream> first, Supplier<IntStream>... streams) {
    Stream<int[]> result = first.get().mapToObj(i -> new int[]{i});

    for (Supplier<IntStream> s : streams) {
        result = nest(result, s);
    }

    return result;
}

private static Stream<int[]> nest(Stream<int[]> source, Supplier<IntStream> target) {
    return source.flatMap(b -> target.get().mapToObj(i -> {
        int[] result = new int[b.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, 0, b.length);
        result[b.length] = i;
        return result;
    }));
}
```

Another one which is not thread-safe, but avoid extra copies:

```
public static Stream<int[]> nest(Supplier<IntStream>... streams) {
    final int[] buffer = new int[streams.length];
    Stream<int[]> result = Stream.of(buffer);

    for (int n = 0; n < streams.length; n++) {
        result = nest(result, streams[n], n);
    }

    // Might need to perform a copy here, if indices are stored instead of being consumed right away.
    // return result.map(b -> Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length));
    return result;
}

private static Stream<int[]> nest(Stream<int[]> source, Supplier<IntStream> target, int index) {
    return source.flatMap(b -> target.get().mapToObj(i -> {
        b[index] = i;
        return b;
    }));
}
```

Usage:

```
nest(
    () -> IntStream.range(0, 2),
    () -> IntStream.range(0, 2), 
    () -> IntStream.range(0, 3))
    .forEach(indices -> System.out.println( Arrays.toString(indices)));
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void recursiveFor(Deque<Integer> indices, int[] ranges, int n) {

    if (n != 0) {

       for (int i = 0; i < ranges[n-1]; i++) {

          indices.push(i);
          recursiveFor(indices, ranges, n-1);
          indices.pop();
       }
    }

    else {

       // inner most loop body, access to the index values thru indices
       System.out.println(indices);
    }
}
```

Sample call:

```
int[] ranges = {2, 2, 2};

recursiveFor(new ArrayDeque<Integer>(), ranges, ranges.length);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String fors(int n){
StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        bldr.append('\t');
    }
    bldr.append("for() {\n");
}
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        bldr.append('\t');
    }
    bldr.append("}\n");
}
return bldr.toString();
}
```

Creates a nice nested for-loop skeleton ;-)
Not completely serious and i'm aware that a recursive solution would have been more elegant.

Comment: no, i'm just saying the question is not clear. The whole issue could also be something like "how do i get my IDE to give me a n-level for-loop template". My code is pretty far away from generating code at runtime, it was meant as code-generation at development-time, aka templates. Btw. the author has not once said he wanted to execute the loops right away. I am just interpreting the question a little different than the other people who answered it before me.

Comment: You can always generate a perl file from java code and then execute it. :) And we are totally serious about doing so. :)

Answer (score 0):

my first time answering a question but i felt like i needed to share this info
of 
`

```
for (x = 0; x < base; ++x) {
  for (y = 0; y < loop; ++y) {
      DoSomething();
  }
}
```

being equivalent to

```
for (x = 0; x < base*loop; ++x){
    DoSomething();
}
```

so if you wanted an n number of nests, it can be written using division between `base` and `loop` so it could look something as simple as this:

```
char[] numbs = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
     public void printer(int base, int loop){
       for (int i = 0; i < pow(base, loop); i++){
         int remain = i;
         for (int j = loop-1; j >= 0; j--){
           int digit = remain/int(pow(base, j));
           print(numbs[digit]);
           remain -= digit*pow(base, j);
         }
         println();
       }
     }
```

so if you were to type `printer(10, 2);` it would print out:

```
00
01
02
03
04
...
97
98
99
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me really nice - I had to select from some alternatives, which were stored in myAlternativePaths and the basic idea is that I was trying to construct next selection, and when there was an "overflow" in one dimension / component, you just reinitialize that dimension and add one to the next.

```
public boolean isValidAlternativeSelection (int[] alternativesSelected) {
    boolean allOK = true;
    int nPaths= myAlternativePaths.size();
    for (int i=0; i<nPaths; i++) {
        allOK=allOK & (alternativesSelected[i]<myAlternativePaths.get(i).myAlternativeRoutes.size());
    }
    return allOK;
}


public boolean getNextValidAlternativeSelection (int[] alternativesSelected) {
    boolean allOK = true;
    int nPaths= myAlternativePaths.size();
    alternativesSelected[0]=alternativesSelected[0]+1;
    for (int i=0; i<nPaths; i++) {
        if (alternativesSelected[i]>=myAlternativePaths.get(i).myAlternativeRoutes.size()) {
            alternativesSelected[i]=0;
            if(i<nPaths-1) {
                alternativesSelected[i+1]=alternativesSelected[i+1]+1;
            } else {
                allOK = false;
            }
        }
 //       allOK=allOK & (alternativesSelected[i]<myAlternativePaths.get(i).myAlternativeRoutes.size());
    }
    return allOK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to solve this problem and eventually have created this simple [solution](https://github.com/0x100/n-loops).

For example, suppose we need to generate loops like this dynamically:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 2; k < 4; k++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(i, j, k));
        }
    }
}
```

So, we can implement it with a such builder:

```java
new Loops()
    .from(0).to(2)
    .from(1).to(3)
    .from(2).to(4)
    .action(System.out::println);
```

The result of execution:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I hope it will useful for someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to work on data and not just numbers. Following solution could be tried:

```
class WordGenerator {
    //My custom spell checker. 
    //It returns an empty string if the word is not there in dictionary
    public static MySpellChecker spellCheck;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        spellCheck = new MySpellChecker();
        
        List<String> consonants = List.of("c","t");
        List<String> vowels = List.of("a","o","");
        
        //adding to this list will increase nesting
        List<List<String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add(consonants);
        input.add(vowels);
        input.add(vowels);
        input.add(consonants);
        
        
        MyForLoop fLoop = new MyForLoop(input.listIterator(),       //for nesting loops
                                        new ArrayList<String>(),    //loop state
                                        //action to perform in innermost loop
                                        (state)->spellCheck.check(String.join("", state))); 
        //start execution
        fLoop.accept("");
        
        //print results
        System.out.println("No of iterations: " + fLoop.getResult().size());
        System.out.println("\nFound words: " + String.join(", ", fLoop.getResult()));
    }
}

class MyForLoop implements Consumer<String> {
    private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private ListIterator<List<String>> itr;
    private Function<List<String>, String> action;
    private List<String> state = new ArrayList<>();

    
    public MyForLoop(ListIterator<List<String>> itr, List<String> collected, Function<List<String>, String> action) {
        this.itr = itr;
        this.action = action;
        state = new ArrayList<>(collected);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void accept(String s) {
        if(!s.isBlank())
            state.add(s);
        
        if(itr.hasNext()) {
            itr.next().stream().forEach(new MyForLoop(itr, state, action));
            if(!state.isEmpty())
                state.remove(state.size()-1);
            itr.previous();
        } else {
            result.add(action.apply(state));
            state.remove(state.size()-1);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<String> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
No of iterations: 36

Found words: , , , , , cat, , coat, , coot, , cot, , , , , , , , , , , , tat, , toat, , toot, toc, tot, , , , , ,
```

Here the code is generating words starting and ending with 'c' and 't', with at max two vowels in between them. You change sequence in `input` list to change word creation.

---

The `MyForLoop` object maintains a `state` list, that holds current iteration state. Each element of the state list gives state of corresponding level of the nested for loop. 
The state can be used in `action`, that gets executed in inner most loop.

---

To keep the demo code short and simple I've cut corners.  It can be improved in many ways.
I've used Jazzy library to check spellings.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jazzy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jazzy</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the interest of conciseness I am putting my code here :

```
void variDepth(int depth, int n, int i) {
    cout<<"\n d = "<<depth<<" i = "<<i;
    if(!--depth) return;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;++i){
        variDepth(depth,n,i);
    }
}
void testVariDeapth()
{   variDeapth(3, 2,0);
}
```

Output

```
 d = 3 i = 0
 d = 2 i = 0
 d = 1 i = 0
 d = 1 i = 1
 d = 2 i = 1
 d = 1 i = 0
 d = 1 i = 1
```