# How to create cartesian product over arbitrary groups of numbers in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, cartesian-product

Let's say I have 2 groups of numbers:

```
{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5}
```

I'd like to create an algorithm (in Java) that outputs the following 6 combinations:

```
1,4
1,5
2,4
2,5
3,4
3,5
```

There can be an arbitrary number of groups and an arbitrary number of members within each group. So in the above example, there are 2 groups with the first group having 3 members and the second group having 2 members. Another example is the following (3 groups, 3 members in first groups and 2 members in second and third groups):

```
{1, 2, 3},
{4, 5},
{6, 7}
```

Which would yield the following 12 combinations:

```
1,4,6
1,4,7
1,5,6
1,5,7

2,4,6
2,4,7
2,5,6
2,5,7

3,4,6
3,4,7
3,5,6
3,5,7
```

How can I do this in Java? I'm trying to use recursion and I've looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313642/simulating-nested-loops) already but I'm still coming up short. Thanks for the help! (P.S. this is not for a homework assignment)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got a bit bored and decided to give it a shot. Should be exactly what you need:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<int[]> input = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    input.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
    input.add(new int[]{4, 5});
    input.add(new int[]{6, 7});

    combine(input, new int[input.size()], 0);
}

private static void combine(ArrayList<int[]> input, int[] current, int k) {
    if (k == input.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.print(current[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.get(k).length; j++) {
            current[k] = input.get(k)[j];
            combine(input, current, k + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you can use libraries, [Guava's](http://google.github.io/guava/) [`Sets.cartesianProduct(List<Set<E>>)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-) does *exactly* what you're looking for.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach (not necessarily the most efficient) might be to take a divide and conquer approach.  It's relatively simple to find all the permutations of two groups (the dumbest way is just nested for loops).  Let's say you write a function called `permute` and it does `permute(A,B)` where A (e.g. {(1), (2), (3)}) and B (e.g. {(4), (5)} are groups of numbers and it returns you all the permutations of A & B as a single group (e.g {(1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5)}).

So when you have N groups instead of 2, the easiest thing to do is just pick off small portions of the problem.  Let's say you have groups A, B and C.  Rather than worrying about them all separately, you can think of it as something like:

`permute(permute(A,B),C)`

Find all the permutations of A and B first.  Once you have that result, find all the permutations of that result with C.  And four groups A, B, C, D might look like:

`permute(permute(permute(A,B),C),D)`

And so on.  At each step along the way, you take the current permutation result and permute it with the next group in the list of groups that you got as input.  You're only ever combining two groups at a time, so the algorithm doesn't have to change depending on the number of groups you get as input.

When you're doing recursion, there are a few major questions you need to answer:

1. Can you recursively break down the problem into smaller, more solvable problems?  I think the examples above prove that you can.
2. What is the base case?  What is the solution that will cause the recursion to stop and unwind?  It should generally be something really simple that your recursion can work down towards.  In this case, it probably comes down to something like `permute(A,{})` where {} is the empty set.
3. What is the recursive case?  How will you break off a chunk of the problem and recurse on a smaller subset of the problem?  I think the initial explanation gives you one way of potentially doing this.  Just break off one group at a time and permute it with your ever-growing result.

There are certainly other solutions to this problem, this is just the first that popped into my head.  As N gets bigger and bigger, this algorithm will get prohibitively slow since it's not very efficient.

So even if you don't use this solution, I hope it gets you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

How about the following pseudo code (w/o recursion)

```
// Create the initial result filled with the first set of numbers
List result = new List()
For each number in the first set
   result.add(new List(number))

// Iterate over the following sets to permutate over
For each remaining set S
   List newResult = new List()
   For each list L in result
     For each number N in S
       newResult.add(copy of L with N added)
   result = newResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a Cartesian product of an arbitrary number of lists using the *map and reduce* approach.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNj9MwEL3nV8wxQdmsGj4O3SUSQhyQ4LTcEAfXnXZdHNuyJ4sqtL@9jJ2mH8qmBQkf6tp@4zdv3jgb8SRurEOzWf7c7VTrrCfY8GbVkdLVq7tstBfIo2irj1ZrlGR9mMY8pOkuy6QWIcA3DAS/M@DhuoVWEgIJ4unJqiW0QpmcI5RZf/8Bwq9DsQfH8UUFuk8/nw3hGn3TgOZlgPfwwXuxDZUI8Tw/hAzj/HhWQl3C66K8gntTwturoHdFweqGs9tbkMITBiUMOG@XnSSwK@CV8AtFXvgtmK5doI/bKf2LAqVjdQm2r2hejBJiUo/OY0BDgEI@Amps4yIyp2gQgf8FLqxGsibtje6pWuHyhL7pK3ugTCe97vm8Fz5O4ySd3vX7o6De1KZpJqMq2XdTfuyqimwqcVG8qDl0bcu9w2pYphPKh6GkoAzZg94JsR7ZHMyTYO6IONXFoHw2Xe1Tq227UCblkLiVMezruakj3pUW9JXLmcCzgbC@TnhGbKQgZGr8G60vGp3468jfu1XZ1T6nshdSX09lJCr6NZ/3Uv4h/KL3Fy1IdnPpT634jz1m6RH9LxUwvmBsHW0nusn6TzrgcHHMokrw/eXnnwjbkeuOl0hXrTieH27@sA2EbEXHVXT8ZEgbjo2g5@x5t/sD)

```java
List<List<Integer>> lists = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3),
        Arrays.asList(4, 5),
        Arrays.asList(6));

// cartesian product of an arbitrary number of lists
List<List<Integer>> cp = lists.stream()
        // represent each element of a list as a singleton list
        .map(list -> list.stream().map(Arrays::asList)
                // Stream<List<List<String>>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // summation of pairs of list into a single list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // combinations of inner lists
                .flatMap(inner1 -> list2.stream()
                        // concatenate into a single list
                        .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                // list of combinations
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());

// output
cp.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 6]
[3, 5, 6]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Cartesian product of map values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506104/16497917)</sup>