# how to write n-level embeded loop with java

Tags: java, algorithm

Given M integers (N1, N2, Nm), I want to write a N-level embedded loop like following :

```
for (int a = 0; a < N1; a++)
  for (int b = 0; b < N2; b++)
    for (int c = 0; c < N3; c++)
      ....
        for (int m = 0; m < Nm; m++)
          operation
```

Since M is a variable, I cannot write fixed number level for-loop. What tricks could help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426878/is-there-any-way-to-do-n-level-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: Not providing a new way to do it, as this has already been answered. Just a comment: by construction, this algorithm runs in exponential time in m. If Ni are not bounded, it is superexponential (for example, if Ni is O (i), then its cost is O (m!); if Ni are O (m), then the cost is O (m^m)).
The recursive solution requires also O (m) space.
Are you sure there's no better algorithm to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

No need for recursion. Instead, think of each iterator as a digit in a number. When you increment the number, you increment the last digit, and if it exceeds the limit (normally 10), it's set to 0, and the digit to the left of it is increased, repeating the overflow logic.

In this case, each "digit" is an independent counter, each with their own "limit", i.e. the value of the given Nx. If you store those limit values in an array, and keep the counters in a same-size array, the logic is fairly simple.

Here is an example of an optimized version, that uses a label to exit directly from a nested loop:

```
int[] n = { 3, 4, 5 }; // m = 3: N1 = 3, N2 = 4, N3 = 5

int[] i = new int[n.length]; // All "digits" are 0
LOOP: for (;;) {
    // operation using i[] here, e.g.
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));

    // Process "digits" from last to first
    for (int j = i.length - 1; ; j--) {
        if (j < 0) // Exit main loop if first "digit" overflowed
            break LOOP;
        if (++i[j] < n[j]) // Increment "digit", and if not overflowed:
            break;         //   exit digit-loop, i.e. loop back to process
        i[j] = 0; // Reset "digit" to 0, then process next (to left) "digit"
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 4]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 4]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 3, 0]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 3, 2]
[0, 3, 3]
[0, 3, 4]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 0, 4]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 0]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 0, 4]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 4]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: A bug: if any of the `int[] n`-es is zero, you will go in doing something for `[0,0,...,0]` even if nothing must be done. Because you are doing all the bookkeeping at the end of the cycle.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Not a bug at all. I showed the logic of the algorithm, assuming valid inputs. Input validation such as `assert i.length > 0` and `assert i[j] > 0` is not included since it has nothing to do with the algorithm. See, even you didn't even consider that e.g. input `[2, -3, 4]` is bad too, so why only focus on `0`?

Comment: "I showed the logic of the algorithm, assuming valid inputs." Ah, OK. An assumption worth mentioning earlier than the comments, I s'pose.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi There are gazillions of answers with sample code here on StackOverflow that are simplified to show the relevant logic, without all the overhead of guard conditions and exception handling, because that would just obscure the point. None (or very few) of them even mentions anything about it. Are you going to comment on all of them about missing guard conditions too? --- Anyway, *my* code isn't bundled in a method taking any set of values. It's done immediately after defining a constant set of values that *don't need validation*. As such, my code is *bug free*.

Comment: "Are you going to comment on all of them about missing guard conditions too?" I'm not quite at a crusader-level for solid code, so no, I won't do it. "As such, my code is bug free." So it is.

Answer (score 1):

The same solution as @Andreeas', just with more explanations (he was faster in posting the answer, I'm adding mine to give myself a reason for the time I spent with the explanations):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Multiloop {

  static public void doSomething(int... maxIndexes) {
    // quick check: if any of the maxIndexes is zeo or less
    // there's a snowball in a furnace chance for the most inner loop
    // to get executed
    for(int i=0; i<maxIndexes.length; i++) {
      if(maxIndexes[i]<=0) {
        return; // nothing to do
      }
    }
    // java guarantees all of then are zero after allocation
    int multiIndex[]=new int[maxIndexes.length];

    int currIndexPos=maxIndexes.length-1; // start looping with the last
    do {
      // this happens when the current index reached its correspondent maximum
      // which of course is maxIndexes[currIndexPos]-1
      while(
          currIndexPos>=0 && 
          multiIndex[currIndexPos]>=maxIndexes[currIndexPos]-1
      ) {
        currIndexPos--; // search for the prev one to increment
      }
      if(currIndexPos<0) {
        // all the indexes have reached their max  value, we are done
        break;
      }
      // if it's not the last index, we need to increment the current one
      // and reset to zero all the others following it 
      if(currIndexPos<maxIndexes.length-1) {
        // if not at the max value, then it's safe to increment it
        multiIndex[currIndexPos]++;
        Arrays.fill(multiIndex, currIndexPos+1, maxIndexes.length, 0);
      }
      // and now all multicycle indexes are to their proper value
      // we reset the currIndexPos to the max and the do what we need to do
      currIndexPos=maxIndexes.length-1;

      /// Cut along the dotted lines and place your own code
      /// ✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂
      { // the inner-most cycle, using the multicycle indexes as necessary
        // replace it with what you need here
        // **** Just don't screw up the currIndexPos!!! 
        // **** unless you know what you are doing 
        // **** (e.g. breaking any of the "cycles" on the way)
        char nameForIndex='a';
        for(int i=0; i<maxIndexes.length; i++) {
          if(i>0) {
            System.out.print(',');
          }
          System.out.print(nameForIndex+"="+multiIndex[i]);
          nameForIndex++;
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
      // ✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...✂...

      multiIndex[currIndexPos]++;
    } while(true); // the exit condition is handled at the cycle start anyway
  }


  static public void main(String args[]) {
    // a triple cycle with their respective max indexes
    doSomething(2,4,3);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
a=0,b=0,c=0
a=0,b=0,c=1
a=0,b=0,c=2
a=0,b=1,c=0
a=0,b=1,c=1
a=0,b=1,c=2
a=0,b=2,c=0
a=0,b=2,c=1
a=0,b=2,c=2
a=0,b=3,c=0
a=0,b=3,c=1
a=0,b=3,c=2
a=1,b=0,c=0
a=1,b=0,c=1
a=1,b=0,c=2
a=1,b=1,c=0
a=1,b=1,c=1
a=1,b=1,c=2
a=1,b=2,c=0
a=1,b=2,c=1
a=1,b=2,c=2
a=1,b=3,c=0
a=1,b=3,c=1
a=1,b=3,c=2
```

Comment: What is purpose of `do { ... multiIndex[currIndexPos]++; } while(currIndexPos>=0);`? There is *no way* for `currIndexPos >= 0` to ever be false, so it's a hidden forever-loop.

Comment: I do however like the printing of named iterators (`a`, `b`, `c`), even though it's really meaningless, since they are not real variables like in question code, and therefore irrelevant. What would be more relevant is where the `operation` shown in the code would go. Still, up-voting as useful answer.

Comment: @Andreas "the printing of named iterators (a, b, c), even though it's really meaningless" A didacticism streak there, I wanted to help OP relate with the notation s/he used in the original question.  As that code is to be replaced by the actual logic of the problem, any code there will be meaningless  except for "examplification purposes".

Comment: @Andreas "more relevant is where the operation shown in the code would go." the entire block is already place between comments which tells - "cut out and replace with your own code". As it doesn't scream it yet, I might have an idea. There

Answer (score 0):

How about using recursive:

```
int recursive_loop(int var_M){
    if(var_M == destination) return 0;
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<var_M || recursive_loop(var_M+1) ; i++){
            // Do operation here
        }
    }
}
```

I tested with C , it work.

Comment: It would be interesting to see that test.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FINAL 10

int rec_loop(int i){
  if(i == 10) return 0;
  else{
    for(int k=0;k<i || rec_loop(i+1) ;k++){
      printf("This is in %d\n",i);
    }
  }
}

int main(void){
  rec_loop(1);
}

Here are my source code.

Comment: Github source (with a better format): [dynamic for loop](https://github.com/kevinbird61/Fun-part-of-C/blob/master/dynamic%20for%20loop/dynamic_forloop.c)