# Easier way to do many nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to generate a list of all possible combinations of colors(I have 8 different colors) and would like to specify the `length` of the output, without going into the code and adding another loop.

```
for (int s1 = 0; s1 < kinds.length; s1++) {
        for (int s2 = 0; s2 < kinds.length; s2++) {
            for (int s3 = 0; s3 < kinds.length; s3++) {
                for (int s4 = 0; s4 < kinds.length; s4++) {
                    for (int s5 = 0; s5 < kinds.length; s5++) {
                        String[] guess = new String[length];
                        guess[0] = colors[s1];
                        guess[1] = colors[s2];
                        guess[2] = colors[s3];
                        guess[3] = colors[s4];
                        guess[4] = colors[s5];
                        Possible.add(guess);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting every possible permutation of a string or combination including repeated characters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113707/getting-every-possible-permutation-of-a-string-or-combination-including-repeated)

Comment: You only need 1 loop just like you increment a clock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combinatorics: generate all “states” - array combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9632677/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write n-level embeded loop with java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40954694/5221149)

Comment: Thanks, i will look in to your answer @Andreas;

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion instead of loop. The general idea is all possible combinations can be generated from the all possible first colors concat with the combinations of the rest.

```
private static List<String> possibles = new ArrayList<>();

private static void combi(char[] arr, char[] out, int start, int end, int index, int length) {
    if (index == length) {
        possibles.add(new String(out));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= end && end - i + 1 >= length - index; i++) {
        out[index] = arr[i];
        combi(arr, out, i + 1, end, index + 1, length);
    }
}

private static void compute(char[] colors, int length) {
    char[] output = new char[length];
    combi(colors, output, 0, colors.length - 1, 0, length);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] colors = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    int length = 3;
    compute(colors, length);

    for (String possible : possibles) {
        System.out.println(possible);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could someone please explain this a little more.

Comment: @KaminPallaghy updated my answer. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot easier