# Multi-layer loop with uncertain layers

Tags: algorithm

I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

```
int[] array = new int[n];    
for(int i = 0; i < array[0]; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[1]; j++){
        ....
        for(int k = 0; k < array[array.length - 1]; k++){
            do something with i,j, ... , k
        }
    }
}
```

So if I don't know the length of array first, so I can't write the certain layers for the loop, I don't know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you "do something with i,j, ... , k"? Can you show an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426878/is-there-any-way-to-do-n-level-nested-loops-in-java)

Comment: Besides recursion, you can also iterate over the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the sequences (which may be implemented as a recursive function, but depending on the language and libraries you are using may be simpler).

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion:

```
arr = [a, b, c, ... n]

function iterate_one_level(arr, indices) {
  if (arr == []) { 
    do_something_with_indices(indices)
    return;
  }

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    iterate_one_level(arr[1:], indices + [i])
  }
}
```

Alternatively, your language may have something similar to [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this is with recursion:

```
deep_loop(array[], index[]) {
    if array.length == 0     // Finally reached the innermost loop
        do something with index[:]
    else                     // Go down one loop level
        // loop on the first array element
        for n in range 0:array[0] {
            // recur on the rest of the array
            // append this index to the sequence
            deep_loop( array[1:], index[:] + [n] )
```