# How can I create dynamic nested loops in java?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am trying to add array list values in dynamic manner of all combinations using `for loop` . For example adding two elements combination in an array can be done by nested loop. Similarly 3,4,5,6,7,8 like that combination addition is need dynamic for loop generation.  What can I do?

```
static int birthday(List<Integer> s, int d, int m) {

    int l=s.size();
    int count=0;
    int a[]=new int[l];
    for (int x=0; x<l; x++){
        a[x]=s.get(x);
    }
    if(m==2){
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            for (int j=i+1; i<l; i++){
                if(a[i]+a[j]==d){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(m==1){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Above code is for 1 and 2 combinations and for all the 3,4,...10. I want to generate dynamic `for loop`.  Please give solution.

Comment: Think about another approach. The dynamic nested loop will slow down your code. Think of  300 nested loops created dynamically. Your code complexity will be `O(n^300)`

Comment: you can solve this using mathematical calculation. However if you must need dynamic loops try recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to do n-level nested loops in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426878/is-there-any-way-to-do-n-level-nested-loops-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You could use recursion:

```
static int birthday(List<Integer> s, int d, int m) {
    int l=s.size();
    int a[]=new int[l];
    for (int x=0; x<l; x++){
        a[x]=s.get(x);
    }
    return birthday(a, d, m, 0, 0);
}

private static int birthday(int[] a, int d, int m, int start, int sum) {
    if (m == 0) {
        return sum == d ? 1 : 0;
    }
    int count=0;
    for (int i = start; i <= a.length-m; ++i) {
        count += birthday(a, d, m-1, i+1, sum+a[i]);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Some optimisations are possible, if you sort the array and if you can assume that all the elements of the list are positive.